# Javascript data mapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone explain to me how can I implement in a clean way a solution to get a status (string) from combining two other ones?
I need to declare a function which takes two params (two strings) and needs to return another one based on the combination of those two strings.
For ex:

```
carStatus(status, secondaryStatus) => string
```

where secondaryStatus can have multiple options.
I'm thinking using an if/else if statement which returns a third status which I need.
For ex when status is 'OPEN' and secondaryStatus is 'payment1' or 'payment2' or 'payment3', the function must return a new string (status) like 'CONFIRMED'.
So, an example of how I'm thinking to implement at this moment would be something like this:

```
carStatus = (status, secondaryStatus) => {
  if(status === 'OPEN' && (secondaryStatus === 'payment1' || 'payment2' || 'payment3')){
    return 'CONFIRMED';
  } else if(status === 'CANCELLED' && (secondaryStatus === 'payment4' || 'payment5' || 'payment6')){
    return 'REMOVED';
  } else if(status === 'REVIEW' && (secondaryStatus === 'payment2' || 'payment5' || 'payment5')){
    return 'CHECKED';
  }
}

<div>carStatus('OPEN', 'payment1')</div>
```

In div must be rendered 'CONFIRMED'.

In my implementation, I'll have to write I think other 5 else if statements.. so maybe there is a cleaner way to implement this.

My project is written in React, but I'm thinking to put this function in utils folder. Perhaps a solution written in React could be more clean? I don't know.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some sample input and expected results along with a higher level explanation of what you are trying to achieve. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use a lookup object for the various options. Since criteria given is very vague following is a very basic example

```js
const carStatus = (carState, carSecondaryState) => {
  const secondaries = {
    ORDERED: 'CLIENT'
  }
  return `${secondaries[carSecondaryState]}_${carState}`
}

console.log(carStatus('NEW', 'ORDERED'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, but I'm not sure I understand. I updated the question again, maybe it's more clear now. I have a spreadsheet with different statuses for carState and different ones for carSecondaryState. So when carState for example is 'NEW' and carSecondaryState is 'CREATED' or 'ORDERED' or 'PAYMENT_NEW', the new third State must be 'CLIENT_NEW' which I need to get it from the carStatus function. all the states are strings. My question here is how can I create this function in order to return this new third state based on the combinations of those two.Hope my issue is clearer now.

Comment: Still not providing enough of the requested sample data along with expected results for that data so we can determine best approach. Using a switch is not uncommon but a deeper object might be simpler also....depends on data depth

Comment: I've updated the question with a solution I found at this moment with if/else if statements. Maybe my questions it's clearer now.